# PL/SQL to initialize outbound variables?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a C++ program using OCI to call the stored procedure. In my PL/SQL stored procedure test, if not initializing an outbound variable, I might get ["fetched column value is NULL"](http://ora-01405.ora-code.com/) error because in case of `foo != 0`, bar is NULL. So in the first line, I initialize bar first. Is this the right way to handle outbound variable?

```
  FUNCTION function1(
    foo   IN  INTEGER,
    bar   OUT VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN INTEGER
  IS
    ret      INTEGER;
  BEGIN

    bar := ' '; -- do I need to initialize this variable?

    IF foo = 0 THEN
      ret := 0;
      bar := 'a';
    ELSE
      ret := 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN ret;

  END function1;
```

Comment: How can you get a `fetched column value is Null` error when there is no `select` (i.e. `fetch`) in your function? and `bar := ' ';` is not required, but you can do it as `bar := NULL;`

Comment: The sql command executed in C++ looks like `BEGIN\n:ret := function1(:foo, :bar); END;` It does error out even there's no select statement. And I tested it again, doing `bar := NULL;` causes the same error as well!

Comment: Have you tried initializing the variable as shown in the code posted above, and does that eliminate the error?

Comment: I tried `var := NULL` and it's still causing error.

Comment: Functions with OUT parameters are a bad programming style, IMO. I'd recommend coding this as a procedure with two OUT parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set BAR in your program then the variable will be initialized to [the default value of its type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#GUID-518B8827-26CC-4734-B799-ACB038185638__PLSQLSUBPROGRAMPARAMETERMODES-521E28A5) (NULL in this case, and for any type except for a record type with a non-NULL default value).  That's just basic logic.

So your choices are:

1. Accept the default value for the type of your variable.
2. Set BAR to the appropriate value in each branch of the IF statement.

Your posted code uses the first option.  In the simple logic you present that is the approach I would take.  If the internals were more complicated - an IF or a CASE with many branches - I would choose to have every branch explicitly set the value, because that would probably make the code's intent clearer.

Comment: bar is an OUT parameter, which means it will be NULL at the start of the function call. Not "whatever value it had before you called function1()".

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - quite right.  I happened to have been working with IN OUT parameters, and I had their behaviour on the brain.